# Evaluate XPath And Retrieve Elements into Java List

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodelist

I am using xPath in Java and I would like to retrieve the nodes `team1_win_perc`, `team2_win_perc` and `draw_perc`. Here is the xml document:

```
<stats timestamp="1628874073" date="08/13/2021 12:01:13">
    <common>
        <EV_AVERAGE_HOME>0.006669</EV_AVERAGE_HOME>
        <EV_AVERAGE_AWAY>0.00193</EV_AVERAGE_AWAY>
        <EV_AVERAGE_DRAW>0.007402678</EV_AVERAGE_DRAW>
    </common>
    <games>
        <id348812>
            <gameid gsid="3509729">348812</gameid>
            <league>BUND</league>
            <team1RotationNumber>150540</team1RotationNumber>
            <team1Name>Bayern Munchen</team1Name>
            <team1_win_perc>62.1</team1_win_perc>
            <team2RotationNumber>150541</team2RotationNumber>
            <team2Name>Arsenal</team2Name>
            <team2_win_perc>17.8</team2_win_perc>
            <draw_perc>20.1</draw_perc>
        </id348812>
        <id348813>
            <gameid gsid="3509730">348813</gameid>
            <league>EPL</league>
            <team1RotationNumber>150543</team1RotationNumber>
            <team1Name>Tottenham</team1Name>
            <team1_win_perc>50</team1_win_perc>
            <team2RotationNumber>150544</team2RotationNumber>
            <team2Name>Chelsea</team2Name>
            <team2_win_perc>25</team2_win_perc>
            <draw_perc>25</draw_perc>
        </id348813>
    </games>
</stats>
```

And here's what I've managed to do so far:

```
            final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            final Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlResponseString.getBytes(UTF_8))));

            final XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            final XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

            NodeList gameIds = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("stats/games/*",
                    document, NODESET);

            final List<Double> homeWinPercentages = new ArrayList<>();
            final List<Double> awayWinPercentages = new ArrayList<>();
            final List<Double> drawPercentages = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < gameIds.getLength(); ++i) {
                Node node = gameIds.item(i);

                homeWinPercentages.add(Double.valueOf((String) xpath.evaluate("stats/games/"
                        + node.getNodeName() + "/team1_win_perc", document, STRING)));
                awayWinPercentages.add(Double.valueOf((String) xpath.evaluate("stats/games/"
                        + node.getNodeName() + "/team2_win_perc", document, STRING)));
                drawPercentages.add(Double.valueOf((String) xpath.evaluate("stats/games/"
                        + node.getNodeName() + "/draw_perc", document, STRING)));

            }
```

Is there a way to avoid evaluating the xml document 3 times? I'd like to create a `List` with class `Probability` which includes the fields `team1_win_perc`, `team2_win_perc` and `draw_perc`.

Comment: XPath and "looping"? Which data exactly do you want on the Java side, can you show the result? Are you aware that XPath is at version 3.1 easily supported for Java using the open source Saxon 10 HE library. Granted, you need to use its own API to exploit the power of XPath 3.1, the JAXP XPath API is geared towards XPath 1.0, but with XPath 3.1 you can easily select and return a sequence of three arrays or an array of three sequences or even a map with three different properties representing your three lists.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/xml/evaluate-xpath-on-dom/

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have managed to get a bit further, edited the question. I would like to know if it's possible to do what I want in a single call, instead of three separate evaluations for each field that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using Saxon 10 (or 9.9) HE with XPath 3.1 to simply return an XPath 3.1 XDM map with three sequences of double values:

```
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.*;

import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SaxonApiException {
        Processor processor = new Processor(false);

        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = processor.newDocumentBuilder();

        XdmNode inputDoc = docBuilder.build(new File("sample1.xml"));

        XdmMap result = (XdmMap) processor.newXPathCompiler().evaluate(
                "let $games := stats/games/* return map { 'homeWinPercentages' : $games/team1_win_perc/number(), 'awayWinPercentages' : $games/team2_win_perc/number(), 'drawPercentages' : $games/draw_perc/number() }",
                inputDoc
        );

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Resulting output:

```
map{"awayWinPercentages":(1.78e1,2.5e1),"drawPercentages":(2.01e1,2.5e1),"homeWinPercentages":(6.21e1,5.0e1)}
```